# Typescript can not resolve index.ts file when using path alias, unless it is included explicitly ($myPackage/index)

Tags: typescript

Assume project structure below:

```
packages/
   utilities/
      index.ts
   app/
      app.ts
tsconfig.json
```

I created path aliases in order to access packages easier between each other, my tsconfig looks like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "$app/*": ["packages/app/*"],
      "$utilities/*": ["packages/utilities/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

Finally my `packages/utilities/index.ts` file is sort of a mid point that imports and exports all utils I want to expose i.e.

```
export { isValidEmail } from '$utilities/validators';
//... etc
```

I initially thought that my app package would be able to do something like this

```
import { isValidEmail } from "$utilities";
// Errors Cannot find module '$utilities' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

But it errors with message above unless I use full path `$utilities/index`

Comment: the path specifies `$utilities/*` will be mapped to the corresponding directory, so just `$utilities` would have to be a separate entry if you want to import it that way. Someone might be able to give a cleaner solution but I think that's just the way it works.

Answer (score 29):

I did this trick and it solved my problem

```
"paths": {
    "@services": ["src/services"],
    "@services/*": ["src/services/*"],
    "@/*": ["src/*"]
},
```

Now I can access `src/services/index` by this line

```
import { useUtil } from '@services';
```

And it also works if I want to access child files/folders

[image]

I also noticed that path aliases on top are prioritized (in intellisense & auto imports) than ones that come after. So it's better to put longer aliases on top and shorter ones in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since *isValidEmail* is exported by index.ts, it is working as expected.

In the *import* statement you have to set **the path to the file** you want to reference, just like you did in the *export* statement.

In this case it will be:

```
import { isValidEmail } from '$utilities/index';
```